# Compare Django TimeField into timezone aware datetime; compare naive time with timezone.now()

Tags: python, django, datetime, pytz

I am using time zone aware objects throughout my app, except where I have a [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#timefield) to represent a generic, daily time of day:

```
class MyModel(models.Modal):
   ...
   start_time = models.TimeField()
```

However, at certain points, I need to compare the current time: `timezone.now()` to the start_time, using the server's timezone, to see if the time has past on any given day.

How can I convert `start_time` to a timezone aware datetime object that can be compared to `timezone.now()` ?

I am using `USE_TZ = True`

Comment: have you tried localize() or as_timezone()?

Comment: also, how is start time created? as a naive datetime or timezone aware one?

Comment: also, why aren't you using a datetimefield?

Comment: It's create in that line of code: `start_time = models.TimeField()`

Comment: @deweyredman TimeField instead of DateTimeField because I didn't want to have to change all the default widgets and validation so that it appears like a DateField.  This is supposed to represent a specific time each day.  Say 2pm.  And is not tied to a specific day.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, though read lots of django docs... couldn't figure out where to start.  Thanks for the localize() and as_timezone() suggestions. I'll look into them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple way:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now, localtime

if model.start_time >= localtime().time():
    # do stuff
```

Note that [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) uses the current time zone, which is the default time zone if not explicitly set. If that's not what you want you can specify the desired time zone as an argument to `localtime()`.